# Define Typescript type of second function parameter as the keyof object that was passed in as first function parameter

Tags: typescript

## Background

Let's say I have this object:

```
const state = {
  sideMenu: {
    isOpen: false,
    foo: "bar"
  },
  foo: "bar"
};
```

I also have a function that changes `state.sideMenu.isOpen` to `true`.

```
dispatch(changeStateBoolean("sideMenu", "isOpen", true));
```

Ignore the `dispatch()` function as that's not relevant for this question. `changeStateBoolean()` returns an object that is used by `dispatch()` to update the state.

## Question

How do I set the type for the second parameter (in this case `"isOpen"`) to be a keyof the first parameter (`"sideMenu"` in this case)?

## Code

Here's what I have so far:

```
interface ChangeState<T> {
  (
    state: keyof State,
    key: keyof State[*** NEED HELP HERE ***],
    value: T
  ): ChangeStateReturn<T>;
}

interface ChangeStateReturn<T> {
  type: T extends boolean
    ? typeof CHANGE_STATE_BOOLEAN
    : T extends number
    ? typeof CHANGE_STATE_NUMBER
    : typeof CHANGE_STATE_STRING;
  payload: {
    state: keyof State;
    key: keyof State["*** NEED HELP HERE ***];
    value: T;
  };
}

export const changeStateBoolean: ChangeState<boolean> = (state, key, value) => {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_STATE_BOOLEAN,
    payload: {
      state,
      key,
      value
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: You should consider editing this code into a [mcve] where the only issue is the one you're trying to address.  That means any code that wouldn't compile in a standalone IDE should be removed or stubbed out.  In this case the answer is going to be to make your function generic in multiple parameters... the first should be the type `K extends keyof State` and the second should be something like `P extends keyof State[K]`, and then you can replace `T` with `State[K][P]`.  I'd give you the code exactly but there's too much editing I need to do to get something that isn't full of errors.

Comment: [Like this](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUM5OALh3wOQCMSBnMKUAcwG4yCESQBXAWwuhfLIAJiQoB7MQBsIcEAOQBfeRBJ5BMGnUbyCDDjz5QdyABaiJ02fKW4FuXAjEhayWpggA5CLQhCAKiaMyAC8yAA8ANLIEAAekCBC1MgA1hAAnmIwaBiQADTIAArRcRAJSakZWejuANoRALoAfAAUZMkkEblkAA4kBV0EAG4k1ZB19TUF9bgAlCGNyM1ukCM5EHPBC2quazXJE931IciDLDa4y57ekP6BIAzNAEQQj-mPMK-Ij7T0948zTGQAHogcgxMk4GkLmsvD5bownnBPo8EJ8AIwAJgAzADgaDwZCgA)

Comment: @jcalz your example works, but I need to put the definition into an interface or type that can be exported. I've tried refactoring your code, which is essentially the same as unional's answer below, but it fails with errors as it sets "key" and "value" to `never` for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: [Here's my attempt](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUM5OALh3wOQCMSBnMKUAcwG4yCESQBXAWwuhfLIAJiQoB7MQBsIcEAOQBfeRBJ5BMGnUbyCDDjz5QdyABaiJ02fKW4FuXKEixEKdJggA5CLQhCAKiaMADxkANLIEAAekCBC1MgA1hAAnmIwaBhYALyJKWkZ7gA0ZAAKEdEQsfFJqelukADaoQC6yDk1+fUQTc1kAHykBAAUrIkkocWCAA4kJZPkAG4kXT0NJb0EAJQkAEoQYJxQILb2jtDwSMh7B0chBOFRMXG5tQXZL52ZEPNlj5XPHTqXx6bQ+QPcPX6g2QUzgyUkYjgImhBAS43mBBmyDmoyWb26LTWG0ULDsuAQYhAtGQtHcXh8-kCID0+PpkEZjFBQwShRhvIWmzaAzUyCg+0OIBRMLhCKRqlGqIx5CmSoIC1GdgINhsuFpkDZvgCjCGACIICbeSaYBbkCbaPRmSbNkxkAB6V3IMQJOG6r4GjnM01wG0mhA2gCMACYAMzOt0er1woA)

Comment: [The fix](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUM5OALh3wOQCMSBnMKUAcwG4yCESQBXAWwuhfLIAJiQoB7MQBsIcEAOQBfeRBJ5BMGnUbyCDDjz5QdyABaiJ02fKW4FuXKEixEKdJggA5CLQhCAKiaMpAQAPKzIANLIEAAekCBC1MgA1hAAnmIwaBhYALwp6ZnZ7gA04QAK0XEQCUmpGVlukADaEQC6yPn1RU0QrW1kAHwAFOHJJBFlggAOJOVT5ABuJL39zeUDBACUJABKEGCcUCAhk8jlgyx2DuDQ8EjI+4fHYQRRsfGJBQ3Fed89OQgC0qHxqX26jUB-U6-0h7n6uEGwWQ0zgaUkYjgImRBHGkWMs3OxmWvz67XWbWsV3sCDEIFoyFo7i8Pn8gRAelJLMgbKC+WGyRKKKFiy2nSRamQUAORxAOJRaIxWNU4VxCxm6qW4TsBBsNlwTMg3N8AUYwwARBBzULzTBrchzbR6BzzVsmMgAPQe5BiZJog2A428jkWuD280Ie0ARgATABmN2e72+-1AA)

Comment: The wrong thing is generic in @unional's answer.   You don't want a generic interface that represents a concrete function, but a concrete interface that represents a generic function.

Comment: I'm happy to write out an answer but I was hoping that you'd put in the effort to turn the code above into a [mcve] without extraneous stuff that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.
You need to use generics to gain access to the types.

I changed you code a bit for example purpose (like removing `CHANGE_STATE_BOOLEAN`).

```
const state = {
    sideMenu: {
        isOpen: false,
        foo: "bar"
    },
    foo: "bar"
};

type ChangeState<
    S,
    V,
    T extends keyof S = keyof S,
    K extends keyof S[T] = keyof S[T]
    > = {
        (state: T, key: K, value: V): ChangeStateReturn<S, V, T, K>;
    }

type ChangeStateReturn<
    S,
    V,
    T extends keyof S = keyof S,
    K extends keyof S[T] = keyof S[T]
    > = {
        type: V extends boolean ? boolean : V extends number ? number : string;
        payload: {
            state: T;
            key: K;
            value: V;
        };
    }

export const changeStateBoolean: ChangeState<typeof state, boolean> = (stateName, key, value) => {
    return {
        type: true,
        payload: {
            state: stateName,
            key,
            value
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it sets `key` type as "never".